# In Emacs revert to global buffer registers

Tags: emacs, spacemacs

I'm using Emacs 26.3 with Spacemacs 0.300 and the registers don't cross from buffer to buffer (global registers).  From what I read on the [EmacsWiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Registers) this is supposed to be global by default.  Mine apparently is not, I can't find anywhere it's being set to local but it's behaving as such.  However, while this:

```
(make-variable-buffer-local 'register-alist)
```

makes a variable local to the buffer, I can't find what to do to make it back global, there's no `make-variable-global` function.

Hope someone has a suggestion, it's frustrating to insert a register I just saved and have it tell me there's nothing there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You **can't** make a variable global that's been declared to always be buffer-local.

This is why this hammer is used relatively infrequently - when you *know* that the variable *should* always be buffer local.

Instead, you typically just use `setq-local` or `set` with `make-local-variable`, which assign a buffer-local value only for the given buffer.  Nothing then prevents some other buffer from *not* having any buffer-local value.

You can of course use `makunbound` to, in effect, start over with your variable unbound. But that's hardly a great solution for a situation where a variable has already been declared to *always be buffer-local* and you want it to *not* have a buffer-local value in some buffer.